# twitter api get only 196 tweets

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, api, laravel-5, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using laravel 5 with twitter api thujohn/twitter
everything works great except can't get more than 196 tweets
this is my function in TweetController

```
public function tweet() 
{ 
    $contents = array();
    $limit = 3200;
    $max_id = null;
    for($count=200 ; $count < $limit ; $count+=200)
    {
        if(null !== $max_id && $max_id == ''){
            break;
        }

        $content = Twitter::getFavorites([
            'count'=>$count,'screen_name'=>'k.s.a95','cursor'=>$max_id,'format'=>'array'
        ]);

        $contents[] = (array)$content;

        //$max_id = $content[count($content) - 1]->id_str;
        if(count($content))
        {
            $last_tweet = end($content);
            $max_id = $last_tweet->next_cursor_str;
             print_r($content);
        } else $max_id = null;

    }
}
```

I hope to help this is 3rd time I asked no response

Answer (score 1):

If you [read the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/favorites/list) you'll see that `count` isn't always exact.

> The value of count is best thought of as a limit to the number of tweets to return because suspended or deleted content is removed after the count has been applied.

Comment: how I could to deal with max_id ?

Comment: You cannot. The count will sometimes be less than 200. Sorry.

Comment: misunderstand, no matter 200 or 196 I need to loop up to finish all tweets.

Comment: Don't worry about max_id - just keep using the cursor.

Comment: I used as you see in the code above but still can't get it.

Comment: like you see in code , it's only get one loop so , it's need to be change value of $cursor , when I've tried I get errors $cursor = Twitter::cursor('next_cursor'); undefined next_cursor

Comment: Have a read of https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/cursoring - try using `next_cursor_str`

Comment: Still undefined next_cursor_str

Comment: You need to post the *full* code - including the `next_cursor_str` so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: public function tweet()
   {
    $s='k.s.a.95';
    $nextCursor = -1;
    if($nextCursor != 0){
        return dd(Twitter::getFavorites(['screen_name' => $s,'cursor' => 
    $nextCursor , 'count' => 200 ]));
     $nextCursor = Twitter::cursor('next_cursor_str');
    }

Comment: No more help !?

Comment: You don't have a loop in your code. Edit your question and show the full code.

Comment: look for update , error comes : Trying to get property of non-object
in TweetController.php (line 33)